# Javascript integer to time string

Tags: javascript, time

I had this test:

```
Implement an function toReadableString(int) that takes an integer that represents number of seconds
from 00:00:00 and returns a printable string format with AM / PM notation.
For ex.
01:00:00 = 3600
07:00:00 = 25200
toReadableString(3600) should return "1:00AM"
toReadableString(25200) should return "7:00AM"
```

And my solution is:

```
function padZero(string){
  return ("00" + string).slice(-2);
}
function toReadableString(time) {
  var hrs = ~~(time / 3600 % 24),
      mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60),
      timeType = (hrs>11?"PM":"AM");
  return hrs + ":" + padZero(mins) + timeType;
}
```

But it fails most of test cases. The test cases are hidden, so I don't know why i failed the test. I have tried most of the test cases I could think of. Any ideas what's wrong with my solution?

Comment: toReadableString(0) returns "0:00AM"

Comment: toReadableString(1) returns "0:00AM"

Comment: I am not convinced this is what you expect

Comment: @eddyP23 _But it fails most of test cases._....It is mentioned in the question post.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: as @eddyP23 mentioned you need to handle the case of 0-3599 seconds... that would be 12:00AM - 12:59AM not 0:00AM

Comment: isn't it 0:00 AM to 0:59 AM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hours are between 0 and 24 (where 0 and 24 are actually 12:00AM)

```
function toReadableString(time) {
  if (time < 0)
    time = 0;
  var hrs = ~~(time / 3600 % 24),
    mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60),
    timeType = (hrs > 11 ? "PM" : "AM");
  if (hrs > 12)
    hrs = hrs - 12;
  if (hrs == 0)
    hrs = 12;
  return hrs + ":" + padZero(mins) + timeType;
}
```

Comment: oh yes you are right, I didn't consider 12 and > 12, no one says 14:00 PM, that's how I failed the test.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
}
```

You can use it now like:

```
alert("5678".toHHMMSS());
```

Comment: what about meridiems?